# Is there a 16 bit version of the 74HC165

Tags: shift-register

Basically 16 bit parallel - in, then shift out, HC family.  Or do I need to just chain two 8 bit shift registers together?

Comment: Kevin M. What does a websearch tell you for "16 bit piso"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything in the 74HC family, but [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/logic-shift-registers/712?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv2207=i16&sf=1&FV=-8%7C712&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=500) are a bunch of 16-bit parts from other families.  Like you said, though, they're easy enough to string together.